# Will using async/await in an express server block all the routes while one is being used?

Tags: javascript, express, async-await

Imagine I have multiple routes

```
/login
/register
/verify
```

And it happens that `/login` route has an async function somewhere

What if for example, during the await of an async function in `/login` (because an user is logging in) , another user is using at the same time the route `/verify` . Will this user experience a delay because of the await? Or does node use some sort of multithreading to avoid the issue? Or should I simply use a promise and a .then instead?

Comment: As much as I know node is multithreading and this is the main power of using as API, is "built-in"

Comment: @dloeda so I suppose that await scope is limited to the async function, right?

Comment: Yes, is limited to that "thread"

Comment: @dloeda Node doesn't simply automatically multi-thread, no. You *can* multi-thread, but you need to do so explicitly, because your code needs to ensure it'll work correctly under multiple threads. The simple answer to the question is that no, while a truly `async` function is being awaited, other requests are *not* blocked. They will interleave as async tasks on the single thread. This is easy to test with awaiting a `setTimeout(100000)` or such…