# How to handle multiple concurrent requests with express?

Tags: node.js, express, asynchronous

We want to have multiple concurrent requests without using node cluster i.e. if we requests 3 times then we should have the execution ending almost at the same time.

This is sample code:

```
const execute_select = async () => {
    const jdbcres = new Driver(Conn.MySQL, {host, port, database})
    const d = await jdbcres.sql(‘SELECT * from db.maindb’); // takes 10 seconds to complete

}

app.post(‘/select, (request, response) => {
 execute_select();
 response.send(‘200’);
});
```

If we execute  http://localhost/select 3 times (at the same time), what happens is the following:

1. We immediately get a response back.
2. Each of the requests are blocked at the following line `const d = await jdbcres.sql(‘SELECT * from db.maindb’)`
3. First one ends within 10 seconds followed by the next one which ends in 10s followed by the next one for a total of about 30seconds.

Is there a way to have calls to /select not waiting for the previous request to end i.e. the total time should be around 10seconds?

My other attempt was to have this in place of the following line: `const d = await jdbcres.sql(‘SELECT * from db.maindb’); // takes 10 seconds to complete`

```
/* const result = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
   setTimeout(() => {
        const d = jdbcres.sql('SELECT * from db.maindb')
        resolve(d);
    }, 20000);
    });
*/
```

**Please find a list of related pages that I have read:**

1. [NodeJS Express Async Not Handling More Requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67475279/nodejs-express-async-not-handling-more-requests)
2. [Will using async/await in an express server block all the routes while one is being used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59965757/will-using-async-await-in-an-express-server-block-all-the-routes-while-one-is-be)
3. [NodeJS Express Async Not Handling More Requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67475279/nodejs-express-async-not-handling-more-requests)
4. [Concurrency in node js express app for get request with setTimeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66973633/concurrency-in-node-js-express-app-for-get-request-with-settimeout)

Comment: What library do you use for mysql?

Comment: You should await for ` execute_select();` like `await execute_select();`

Comment: node-jdbc, if we await on execute_select then any requests  to /select will be blocked in app.post request immediately i.e. we won't get any response

Comment: If you mean [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jdbc) then this library hasn't been updated for two years. It doesn't support promises so using `await` does nothing. The reason it's blocking the thread is that it's poorly designed. I would suggest using `mysql2`

Comment: Yes, we have our code wrapped around it. The issue is that we have lots of dbs and we wanted a generic solution.

Comment: Suppose we have a code which hangs e.g. converting values returned from the select query to an array using toObjArray(). How, do we make that asynchronous? I suppose the same idea can be applied to this question.

Comment: You can use `child_process` to run task in another process or worker thread